# Assembly language program to find the largest number in an array

Tags: assembly, x86-16, unsigned, signed, emu8086

I have an assembly program that should find and print out the largest number in the given array. My problem is I know that the largest number is **ABh** but the program can only read up to **56h**. I noticed that it cannot read large numbers.
Here are my more specific questions:

1. How many bits do 9Ah and ABh have?
2. If these numbers can't be stored in the `AL` register, how would I store these values and compare them to find the largest one?

Here is the code:

```
.MODEL SMALL
 
READ MACRO MSG
    MOV AH,0AH
    LEA DX,MSG
    INT 21H
ENDM

PRINT MACRO MSG
    MOV AH,09H
    LEA DX,MSG
    INT 21H
ENDM

.STACK 100H

ASSUME CS:CODE, DS:DATA
DATA SEGMENT 
 
 CR EQU 0DH
 LF EQU 0AH
    MSG1 DB "The array is: 52H,23H,56H,45H,9AH,ABH$"
    MSG2 DB CR,LF,"The largest number is: $"
    LIST DB 52H,23H,56H,45H,45H,9AH,0ABH
    COUNT EQU 0Fh 
    LARGEST DB 04H DUP (?)
    
DATA ENDS
    
CODE SEGMENT

START:
        MOV AX,DATA
        MOV DS,AX
        
        PRINT MSG1
        
        MOV SI,OFFSET LIST
        MOV CL,COUNT
        MOV AL,[SI]
        
AGAIN:  CMP AL,[SI+1]
        JNL NEXT
        MOV AL,[SI+1]

NEXT:   INC SI
        DEC CL
        JNZ AGAIN
        
        MOV SI,OFFSET LARGEST
        MOV [SI],AL
        
        ;HOW TO PRINT VALUE OF AL?
        
        
        MOV AH,4CH
        INT 21H
        
CODE ENDS
END START
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

- Setting `COUNT` to `0Fh`  seems wrong as your array contains 7 elements, not 15.
- You might also have an off-by-one error, since your loop iterates `COUNT` times but has already processed the 0th element of the array before entering.  Either that or you want to set `COUNT` to the number of elements minus 1.
- These are all 8-bit integers, and `AL` can hold them just fine.  But...
- `JNL` jumps based on the result of a signed compare.  As signed 8-bit integers, `9Ah` and `ABh` are negative and therefore the greatest element is indeed `56h`.  If you want to treat them as unsigned, replace `JNL` with `JNB`, so that you jump on the result of an unsigned compare.
- For ways to print the value, see the links at https://stackoverflow.com/tags/x86/info under "Printing integers".